# Oracle APEX 19.2 moving application to another host

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I exported an application from one oracle apex 19.2 host and sucessfuly imported it to another oracle apex 19.2 host. But when I start the application, I get the following error:

```
You are not authorized to view this application, either because you have not been granted access, or your account has been locked. Please contact the application administrator.
Access denied by Application security check

Technical Info (only visible for developers)
is_internal_error: true
apex_error_code: APEX.AUTHORIZATION.ACCESS_DENIED
component.type: APEX_APPLICATION_AUTHORIZATION
component.id: 14644239902526063
component.name: Reader Rights
```

So what could be the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: You have an application Authorization Scheme that is denying you access. The exact cause should become more obvious when you identify which Authorization Scheme is the problem and how it is configured. Go to the Shared Components > Security and note which Authorization Scheme is being used. Next, navigate to Shared Components > Authorization Schemes and select the correct scheme. How is it configured?

Comment: Just venturing a guess here... If the authorization scheme requires network access, such as LDAP, then it's possible the new host has not been configured to communicate over the necessary protocol/ports. Search for creating an ACL in Oracle Database if that's the case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Validate Security Attributes in your application. If you're using *Access Control User Role Assignments* for *Source for Role or Group Schemes*, you need to add the roles and propers users in *Shared Components* -> *Application Access Control*.

[image: Edit Security Attributes]

Answer (score 1):

May be you forget to assign the rol to your admin user...
Go to "Access Control / Shared Components / App Access Control
Then assign rol to users.
Keep in mind that you need to create the user and assign the rol in this page.

According to APEX DOCs, when you export (and the import) an app, it is needed to do this manually.

Hope this help.
Regards